# Vertical alignment in the tables with pictures (epsfig)

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I have a table with two columns. The column on the left contains a picture (\epsfig) the column on the right contains the description.

The description starts on the same height as the lower end of the epsfig

I would like the description to start on the same height as the beginning of the epsfig.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: people generally like a minimal working example. Post the minimal code necessary to illustrate your problem please! you will get a much more precise answer this way!

Comment: »epsfig« is obsolete and superseded by »graphicx«.

Comment: I think a more descriptive title would be "Vertical alignment in the tables with pictures". So people can find the question in the future.

Comment: I agree, but I am forced to use epsfig by the publishing company. This is as well the reason for net sending an example, since it is a "customized table environment".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work within a table. It aligns the picture and the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
%raise the text and put it in a box
\raisebox{-\height}{\parbox{5cm}{%
\blindtext%
}}
% raise the picture \rule{}{} is a dummy for \includegraphics...
& \raisebox{-\height}{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}\\\addlinespace
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a custom `\sidebyside` macro to center (vertically) the text with respect to the figure on the left:

[image: sidebyside in action]

And the macro itself, to put in the preambula:

```
\newsavebox{\leftbox}
\newlength{\leftboxheight}
\newcommand{\sidebyside}[2]{
  \sbox{\leftbox}{#1}
  \settoheight{\leftboxheight}{\usebox{\leftbox}}
  \usebox{\leftbox}
  \raisebox{0.5\leftboxheight}{#2}
}
```

Details and mini-documentation are [here](http://sovety.org.ru/files/sidebyside.pdf). You can easily adjust the position by changing the first argument to `\raisebox`.

Comment: Thanks to you as well, I need to use the customized table environment.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the TeX faq at texfaq.org: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-topgraph

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this unfortunately does not solve my problem.